# rewrite rules with query sign

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

need your help with a rewrite rule. I need to rewrite the word some-ads to just ads and keep all the data after.
So for example I'd like to go from

```
http://myserver.com/some-ads?as=184252&pr=0101
```

to

```
http://myserver.com/ads?as=184252&pr=0101
```

I tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^some-ads$ http://myserver.com/ads?%1 [L]
```

But everything after the `?` sign is ignored. How can I keep the query sign and all data?

Thank you!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This may do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^some-ads$ http://myserver.com/ads [QSA,R=301,L]
```

QSA: QueryString Appended.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*) is not required for your specific case.

R=301 is added to redirect URL, visible on Browser's addressbar.

#### If you don't want redirect, but a simple rewrite,

you'd better use this simpler form:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^some-ads$ /ads [QSA,L]
```

#### ADDED:

Your original code also worked in our Debian/Apache2 Server.